# How to send Text RTD Record from nfc to android?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, nfc, nfc-p2p, lib-nfc

I am trying to communicate nfc module pn532 with Android mobile.

I used [itead nfc](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=78966) module interface with rasberry pi and using libnfc(1.7.1) and libllcp for communicate with mobile.

After run libllcp test program (snep-client.c) example,

```
$ LIBNFC_LOG_LEVEL=3 ./examples/snep-client/snep-client
```

I get this error

> "error libnfc.driver.pn532_spi Unable to wait for SPI data. (RX)
>
> libllcp.mac.link Could not send 2 bytes"

**Log :**

```
debug libnfc.bus.spi RX: 00
debug libnfc.bus.spi TX: 02
debug libnfc.bus.spi RX: 00
debug libnfc.bus.spi TX: 02
debug libnfc.bus.spi RX: 00
debug libnfc.bus.spi TX: 02
debug libnfc.bus.spi RX: 01
debug libnfc.bus.spi TX: 03
debug libnfc.bus.spi RX: 00 00 ff 20
debug libnfc.bus.spi RX: e0
debug libnfc.bus.spi TX: 03
debug libnfc.bus.spi RX: d5
debug libnfc.bus.spi TX: 03
debug libnfc.bus.spi RX: 57
debug libnfc.bus.spi RX: 00
debug libnfc.bus.spi TX: 03
debug libnfc.bus.spi RX: 01 df 0b 63 89 dc 35 50 ec 59 a2 00 00 00 0e 32 46 66 6d 01 01 11 03 02 00 13 04 01 96
debug libnfc.bus.spi RX: 96
debug libnfc.bus.spi TX: 03
debug libnfc.bus.spi RX: 00
libllcp.mac.link (pn532_spi:/dev/spidev0.0) nfc_initiator_poll_dep_target() succeeded
libllcp.mac.link (pn532_spi:/dev/spidev0.0) LLCP Link activated (initiator)
libllcp.llc.link llc_link_configure (0x143d80, (nil), 0)
libllcp.llc.link mq_open (/libllcp-2532-0x143d80-up)
libllcp.llc.link mq_open (/libllcp-2532-0x143d80-down)
libllcp.llc.link LLC Link started successfully
libllcp.mac.link Sending 2 bytes
libllcp.mac.link LTOs: 1000 ms (local), 100 ms (remote)
debug libnfc.chip.pn53x InDataExchange
debug libnfc.chip.pn53x Timeout value: 1100libllcp.llc.llc (0xb6d16470) Link activated
libllcp.llc.llc (0xb6d16470) mq_receive+
debug libnfc.bus.spi TX: 01 00 00 ff 05 fb d4 40 01 00 00 eb
debug libnfc.bus.spi TX: 02
debug libnfc.bus.spi RX: 01
debug libnfc.bus.spi TX: 03
debug libnfc.bus.spi RX: 00 00 ff 00 ff 00
debug libnfc.chip.pn53x PN53x ACKed
debug libnfc.bus.spi TX: 02
debug libnfc.bus.spi RX: 00
debug libnfc.bus.spi TX: 02
debug libnfc.bus.spi RX: 00
.
.
.
.
***** AFTER SOME SAME LOG********
.
.
.
debug libnfc.bus.spi RX: 00
debug libnfc.bus.spi TX: 02
debug libnfc.bus.spi RX: 00
debug libnfc.bus.spi TX: 02
debug libnfc.bus.spi RX: 00
debug libnfc.bus.spi TX: 02
debug libnfc.bus.spi RX: 00
debug libnfc.bus.spi TX: 02
debug libnfc.bus.spi RX: 00
error libnfc.driver.pn532_spi Unable to wait for SPI data. (RX)
libllcp.mac.link Could not send 2 bytes
```

I used pn532(itead nfc) module to communicate with android 4.3 (samsung S3).

I used libnfc -> libllcp -> libndef to send data from raspberry pi to android.

**Problem:**

My mobile vibrate when I tap it with nfc module, but not showing any message and error occurs at pi console.

**Questions:**

Is 1.7.1 libnfc version is right to use with libllcp library and snep protocol to send my NDEF message to android?

If I send Text RTD Record to android, than will phone display text on screen?

Please comment your view about this error log, May it help me to solve error.

Thank you

Comment: I solved problem, I use nexus 5 (android lolipop) instead of samsung and it start working.